A flaw in notation of the polynomial vector space $\mathcal{P}(\mathbf{F})$?
In Linear Algebra Done Right, Axler defines what it means for a function to be a polynomial over a field $\mathbf{F}$ (real or complex numbers) as follows:

A function $p : \mathbf{F} \to \mathbf{F}$ is called a polynomial
with coefficients in $\mathbf{F}$ if there exist $a_0, \ldots, a_m \in
   \mathbf{F}$ such that
$$ p(z) = a_0 + a_1z + a_2z^2 + \cdots + a_mz^m $$  for all $z \in
   \mathbf{F}\\$.

$\mathcal{P}(\mathbf{F})$ is the set of all polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbf{F}$.



It's the second bullet I have an issue with. If I say let $p \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbf{R})$, the only piece of information I know, based on the the second bullet above, is that the coefficients of $p$ are in $\mathbf{R}$. But it tells me nothing about the domain or codomain of $p$.
For example, I can define $p_1: \mathbf{C} \to \mathbf{C}$ by
$$
p_1(z) = z^2 + 3z + 1
$$
and $p_2: \mathbf{R} \to \mathbf{R}$ by
$$
p_2(x) = x^2 + 3x + 1
$$
So, we have $p_1, p_2 \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbf{R})$ (also, $p_1, p_2 \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbf{C})$), but they differ in their domains and codomains.
Why do I take issue with this? Because in result 4.16 (see here: https://linear.axler.net/LADR4e.pdf#page=142), we somehow magically "know" the domain of $p$ is $\mathbf{R}$, which is a needed criteria for the proof to work! But as I have mentioned above, there's no possible way of knowing this by merely saying $p \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbf{R})$.
Is this a flaw in the notation of $\mathcal{P}(\mathbf{F})$? Am I crazy for thinking this?

In his book, Axler defines a polynomial to be a function. Since he works with only two fields, $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$, he really avoids some trouble. However, it is true that new trouble appears, too. In my opinion, in his proof of result 4.16, Axler does not really "think of $p$ as an element of $\mathcal{P} (\mathbb{C})$", but instead defines $p_1$: $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ such that $p_1 (x) = p(x)$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$. If "having a flaw" means "being not prefect", then yes, the notation is not flawless. I do not think that you are "crazy for thinking this".

@Juliamisto thanks for your input. Two questions if you don't mind: (1) what would change if we worked with an arbitrary Field? (2) what is $p_1$ defined as for $x \in \mathbb{C}$, where $x \notin \mathbb{R}$?

(1) Things would not change too much, if we worked with a field with infinitely many elements (it is of course that things about "roots" usually change a lot, though). For a field with finitely many elements, the manner in which Axler defines a polynomial should not be used. See the 12th page of the document (the book which you cited) for details. (2) If $p$: $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is defined by $p(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + \dots + a_n x^n$ (where $a_0$, $a_1$, $\dots$, $a_n$ are real numbers), then we simply define $p_1$: $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ by $p_1 (z) = a_0 + a_1 z + \dots + a_n z^n$.

In the first bullet point, the author defined what a polynomial with coefficients in $F$ is:

A function $p: F \rightarrow F$ is a polynomial with coefficients in $F$ if there exists $a_0, a_1, \ldots, a_m \in F$ such that
$$
     p(z) = a_0 + a_1 z + \ldots + a_m z^m \ \forall z \in F
$$

The second bullet point says that $\mathcal{P}(F)$ is a collection of all functions satisfy the first bullet point. Therefore, if $p \in \mathcal{P}(F)$
then $p: F \rightarrow F$.
In your example, $p_1 \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{C})$ as $p_1: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$. Similarly, $p_2 \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ as $p_2: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.
Likewise, in the result 4.16, $p \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$, we know from the first bullet point that $p: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Ah I see, gosh how did I miss that. What about a polynomial $p : \mathbf{R} \to \mathbf{C}$? Is this undefined then?

@PaulAsh Maybe we can extend it to $p: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ so $p \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{C})$ ?

Got it, makes sense. Thank you!
